# Excel Charts Showing Blank and with Data as Header

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, charts

I'm having an issue creating some tables.
What I want to do is create a tab with a series of charts within it to represent distributions of various data point from specific columns in a primary/master tab.

The issue I am having is that when I select the data I want the chart to have, the selected data is positioned in the 'Chart Title' position and the chart itself shows as blank.

I also then tried selecting the 'Plot Area' object with the wider chart box and reselecting the data but that does not make any difference.

I am using Excel on a Macbook.

I've attached some screenshots below, any more detail needed, please ask.

Sample of Data:

[image]

`Malformed Chart`

[image: Chart as it appears once data has been selected]

`Data Selection`

[image: Data that I have selected for the above image]

When I right click on the 'Plot Area' placeholder and select the data again I just end up with this...

[image]

Comment: Try switching the ranges for "Name" and "Y values" around

Comment: That gets better values but the chart is still blank

Comment: Can you post sample data? can you get a chart working with a small table (say 2x3 cells)?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad edited the original post. It's just a single column of strings

Comment: If you have no numbers, then no wonder the chart is blank. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Get a representation of the number of occurrences of each type

Comment: Get a list of all the types (with no duplication), then use `COUNTIF` to get the numbers

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a pivot table of your column of data. Put Social Landlord into the rows area and also into the values area. Since it's text, Excel should default to a count of Social Landlord in the values area. Your pivot table will be two columns, with the text labels in the first column and the counts in the second. If you want, you can sort it and make a horizontal bar chart from the pivot table.

[image: Pivot Table of a List of Labels]